# How to check if selected text overflows into certain class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Context:**

I'm trying to figure out a way to tell if a certain user-highlighted portion of text includes a class, and if it does, disallow the user from highlighting that block of text.

On my website, users can create their own articles. On these articles, users can highlight text and comment on it. Take this text for example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod

If this was a users's article, I could go in and highlight the text "Lorem ipsum", like so:

> "**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do
>   eiusmod."

This creates a class around the highlighted text which has `background-color` set to `grey`.

At this point, I want to disallow the user from highlighting any of the text that has already been highlighted ("Lorem ipsum"), because I have problems with highlighting words that are part of more than one highlight correctly.

So, I need a system where, when the user makes a highlight that includes any part of the text that is already contained in a class, for example:

> "Lorem **ipsum dolor** sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do
>   eiusmod"

*With the highlight "ipsum dolor" including "ipsum", which was already highlighted and already has a class name*

That then an alert pops up and the highlight is not made.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have already tried using setting the css property `user-select: none;`

- This doesn't allow the user to highlight the text that has this class directly
- Though users can still start their cursor at a different point and bleed into the text with this property, making it possible to make the highlight.

**Question & Example JSFiddle:**

How can I tell if highlighted text contains text from a certain class?

Here's an example of what I want to happen when the user highlights text that is contained in another class:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
    checkIfTextisAlreadyHighlighted();
});

function checkIfTextisAlreadyHighlighted() {
   var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel) {
       alert("This text contains the class *class name here* and cannot be highlighted.");
    }
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
    background-color: lightGrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='highlighted'>Selecting this text should make this message appear if text that already contains class is highlighted</span>. More random text.
</div>
```

Comment: I know I am not answering the question, but can you clear the previous highlight before starting another highlight ? So at any point of time there will be no more than 1 highlight. I think this is common in UX and we don't need to educate user on that.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski what do you mean by clear the highlight?

Comment: With your approach, when user select text, you will annotate those selected text with a css class right? "clear the highlight" means, when user start another text selection, remove the class from the previous selection, after that ,annotate the current selected text. Then you will not have more than 1 highlight at a time. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski I see what you're saying. The problem with that is that I don't want to allow the user to be able to highlight any part of text that has already been highlighted. The problem is not that the user can't highlight part of what's been highlighted, but instead that I don't know how to disallow the user from highlighting text that has already been highlighted. So, if the user highlights part of text that has already been highlighted, he/she should be alerted to the fact that they can't make that highlight. Does that make sense?

Comment: can you clarify "_Though users can still start their cursor at a different point and bleed into the text with this property, making it possible to make the highlight._" `user-select: none;` will make users not able to select text. so no need for JS to disable selection.

Comment: @ROOT the thing is the only text with that class on the articles is the text that has previously been highlighted. So, the user can start the highlight outside of the text with the class that contains `user-select: none;` and move into the text, which still allows the selection to be made.

Comment: @CarsonD did you have the time to check my answer?

Comment: @Dekel yes, sorry. I'm currently trying to implement it to make sure it works on this specific problem, just to make sure I don't have any confusion. But the solution seems to be perfect. I'll be sure to finish before the bounty is up (this is my first bounty as well)

Comment: Sure, no problem :) just wanted to make sure everything works. If you have some other issues with the actual implementation please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some explanations on the following implementation:

1. Extract the selection and get the range.
2. Once you have the range - check if the start & end is the same node (if so - we will not get the container element and therefor there is no classname that we can check agains - we need to check if the parent has the relevant class).
3. If we have multiple elements in our selection - we can check if the cloned elements has the class we are after (using the querySelector).
4. (This was not part of the question) - you can also remove the selection if you need it.

Here is a working example:

```js
$("div").mouseup(function() {
    checkIfTextisAlreadyHighlighted();
});

function resetSelection() {
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}

function checkIfTextisAlreadyHighlighted() {
    const classToSearch = 'highlighted';
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    if (range.startContainer === range.endContainer && range.startContainer.parentElement.classList.contains(classToSearch)) {
        alert(`This text contains the class ${classToSearch} and cannot be highlighted.`);
        resetSelection();
    } else {
        if (range.cloneContents().querySelector(`.${classToSearch}`) !== null) {
            alert(`This text contains the class ${classToSearch} and cannot be highlighted.`);
            resetSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
    background-color: lightGrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='highlighted'>Selecting this text should make this message appear if text that already contains class is highlighted</span>.
  More random text.
  <span class='highlighted'>Selecting this text should make this message appear if text that already contains class is highlighted</span>.
  More random text.
</div>
```

Comment: It always amazes me when I see a bountied question, that should be important for the OP, with an IMHO good answer, and where the OP doesn't even comment on it.

Comment: @vals not always this is a top priority :) and there are still 5 more days for the bounty. I believe it's OK to keep such question open (with the bounty) for the last day to get more attention and maybe more answers (or different approaches). I'm sure there are other ways to do what I did there.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid user from selecting that specific highlighted text you can add 
    user-select: none;
to its class.

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: grey;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="highlighted">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod.
```